# Recall Twise UiSwitch action code

Tags: objective-c, xcode7.3

When i execute the code '[switchOutlet setOn:NO animated:NO]' in UiSwitch Action method, it will recall that method again.
I want to block the user to click the switch button, it will accessed only by the admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user can not interact with the UISwitch you can deactivate it with the command

```
 [switchOutlet setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: thanks.. But i want the user to click that switch button and i want to show an alert that 'Only admin can enable it'....